# Use string of class name to new a class

Tags: c#, reflection

I want to use a class name sting to new a class

NameSpace is `Mcs.ControlMaster`

Class Name is `HostTransportCommand`

after check some posts here. I use Activator

```
var msg = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("Mcs.ControlMaster.HostTransportCommand", true));
```

got exception

```
System.TypeLoadException
  HResult=0x80131522
  Message=Could not load type 'Mcs.ControlMaster.HostTransportCommand' from assembly 'Mcs.ControlMaster.UT, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>
```

OKAY, the execution assembly is Mcs.ControlMaster.UT now 。and this class is in Mcs.ControlMaster. then

```
string fileToLoad = @"Mcs.ControlMaster.exe";
AssemblyName assemblyName = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(fileToLoad);
// assemblyName={Mcs.ControlMaster, Version=3.0.19.320, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null}
AppDomain myDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyDomain");
//myDomain={System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.__TransparentProxy}
Assembly myAssembly = myDomain.Load(assemblyName);
//myAssembly={Mcs.ControlMaster, Version=3.0.19.320, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null}
var myFunc = myAssembly.CreateInstance("HostTransportCommand");
// myFunc = null
```

if use

```
Type.GetType("Mcs.ControlMaster.UT, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null", true));
```

will get

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: "The given assembly name or codebase was invalid."
```

definition of HostTransportCommand

```
namespace Mcs.ControlMaster
{
    public class HostTransportCommand : JsonMessage
```

and definition of JsonMessage

```
namespace Mcs.Message
{
  public class JsonMessage : IMcsMessage

namespace Mcs.Message
{
  public interface IMcsMessage
```

How to solve this issue？

Comment: So you're trying to load a type from an assembly which isn't referenced by your project? Why are you loading it into a new AppDomain, rather than into your AppDomain?

Comment: it's unitest project. so the exe is referenced by project. but in getType, will get exception Could not load type 'Mcs.ControlMaster.HostTransportCommand'

Comment: Can you add the definition of `Mcs.ControlMaster.HostTransportCommand` to your question?

Comment: update HostTransport definition in post. the parent class is in another dll. and without source code

Comment: Bit convoluted for a unit test project, don't you think? What are you trying to achieve? There's possibly an easier way to test this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Source code demo in my Github (batressc)](https://github.com/batressc/LoadingAssemblies)

I created 2 projects (.net framework class libraries) using your classes definitions: `Mcs.ControllerMaster` and `Mcs.Message`. I reference `Mcs.ControllerMaster` inside of third project `Msc.WindowsConsole` (Windows console application).

For testing purposes, I added 2 properties to `HostTransportCommand`:

```
public class HostTransportCommand : JsonMessage {
    public string PropertyOne { get; set; }
    public int PropertyTwo { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in `Main` method I follow this steps:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        // Getting current execution directory
        var currentExecutingPath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
        string dirtyDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(currentExecutingPath);
        string directory = dirtyDirectory.Replace(@"file:\", "");

        // Loading assembly in app context
        var externalAssembly = File.ReadAllBytes($"{directory}\\Mcs.ControlMaster.dll");
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(externalAssembly);

        // Now is loading. Creating an instance of class
        // The object type is "ObjectHandle"
        var hostTransportCommandInstance = Activator.CreateInstance("Mcs.ControlMaster", "Mcs.ControlMaster.HostTransportCommand");

        // Getting properties for validate instance creation
        // Using Unwrap() method we can access to true Type (HostTransportCommand)
        var hostTransportCommandType = hostTransportCommandInstance.Unwrap().GetType();
        var hostTransportCommandProperties = hostTransportCommandInstance.Unwrap().GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        // Showing information about type HostTransportCommand
        Console.WriteLine($"The type from Mcs.ControllerMaster is {hostTransportCommandType}");
        Console.WriteLine("Showing public properties (they was added for testing purposed):");
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in hostTransportCommandProperties) {
            Console.WriteLine(property.Name);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you solve it. I can get the object now.